# What is the meaning of 'OFFSET' => 1 (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this php code for wordpress random post plugin:

```
<?php
global $post;
$tmp_post = $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'orderby' => 'rand', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'offset' => 1);
$rand_posts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $rand_posts as $post ) : ?>
    <li><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2><p><?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </p></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php $post = $tmp_post; // reset the $post to the original ?>
```

I wanna know what is the the meaning of the code `'offset' => 1`.i already understand to others such as:

- Numberpost  - how many post you would like to be displayed?
- Orderby – randomly select from the list of our blog post.
- Post_status – selects only the blog post which is on Publish status.
- **Offset - ???**

can someone define this for me.

Comment: offset is where you start. if it is for example set to 10 then it will start at the 10th row of your table. It is used a lot for pagination.

Comment: See this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Posts_list_with_offset

Comment: sorry krike, im having trouble understanding. so if i set this to 1, it will start with what?

Comment: @krike, I didn't check but counting probably starts with 0. So offset 10 would start at the 9th row.

Comment: the code above is to display wordpress random blog post, so that means having offset set to 1 means? 1 means it would start with what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The offset is used for pagination. From the [docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters):

> **offset** (int) - number of post to displace or pass over. Note: Setting offset parameter will ignore the paged parameter.